# Printing in lettuce (python)

Tags: python, lettuce

How to print a string in lettuce?
In `steps.py` just a `print "test"` doesn't print it on stdout.

```
response = generate_string()
print response
```

The above doesn't work in lettuce. I am guessing Lettuce is grabbing all the stdout prints

Comment: What if you make it print what you want as an error with a failed assertion such as assert response == "uNliLelY", "Got response %d" % response ?

Answer (score 0):

adding a '\n' add the end worked in my case.